# WordPress plugin to cache pages for logged in users

Tags: wordpress, caching

There are many WordPress caching plugins but I've never found a plugin to save cached pages for logged in users.

CometCache does that, but it creates a cached page for each user and it is useless.

I have a membership site with 95% of pages that are identical for all the users and I want to cache them once for all users with 24 hours timeout, because they are heavy to load.

Is there a plugin to do that?

Comment: WP Rocket is the best caching plugin I've found for WordPress which will do what you want.  https://wp-rocket.me/

Comment: Hi @Monzio Try Cache Buddy by Mark Jaquith as I feel this will help your needs!

Comment: Wp Super Cache has an option "Don’t cache pages for known users." which can be deselected

Comment: "Don’t cache pages for known users" creates a cached page for each user.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to [try this option](https://monosnap.com/file/ht8QSKY3YTzzSEq2mf4wzZ7cyTv8EL)? Not tested myself.